# Laravel validation se existe um registro filho

Tags: laravel, validation

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma validação padrão que retorna para o usuário um erro se ele tentar deletar um registro pai sendo que existem os filhos.

Tenho uma tabela tipos de veículo, onde eu cadastro carro, moto, por exemplo.
Tenho uma tabela de marcas e uma terceira chamada marca_tipo_veiculo, que associa uma marca a tipos de veículos diferentes.

até o momento só faço essa validação que verifica se o id do tipo do veículo existe

```
 $request->validate([
        'id' => 'required|int|exists:tipos_veiculos,id,deleted_at,NULL',
    ]);
```

Comment: Não acha melhor criar uma chave estrangeira entre as tabelas?

Comment: O relacionamento é n pra n nesse caso... Na tabela de marcas eu quero ter um registro único, como eu dei o exemplo da marca honda, que pode ser tanto para carro e moto. Ou eu teria que criar uma chave composta e duplicar os nomes de marcas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isto criando uma regra de validação customizada:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use app\Models\ModelFilho;

class CheckChildren implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $numFilhos =  ModelFilho::where('id_pai',$value)->count();
        return $numFilhos > 0 ? false : true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute has children and couldn't be deleted.';
    }
}
```

E na validação:

```
$request->validate([
        'id' => [ 'required', 'int', new CheckChildren ]
 ]);
```

Você pode tambem estender a regra "exists":

https://timacdonald.me/foreign-key-validation-rule/

Comment: resolvido! muito obrigado mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Segue a solução adaptada seguindo exemplo a cima:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use App\Models\TypeVehicle;

class CheckTypeVehicleChildren implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $childrens = TypeVehicle::with('brands')->where($attribute, $value)->first();

        return $childrens->brands()->count() > 0 ? false : true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'Existem marcas associadas a este tipo de veículo';
    }
}
```

Controller

```
 public function delete(Request $request)
    {
        $request['id'] = $request->route('id');

        $request->validate([
            'id' => ['bail', 'required', 'int','exists:tipos_veiculos,id,deleted_at,NULL', new CheckTypeVehicleChildren()]
        ]);

        $typeVehicle = TypeVehicle::find($request->id);

        $typeVehicle->delete();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Tipo de veículo deletado com sucesso!'], 200);
    }
```